# Parsing Date in Go

Tags: time, go

I am writing a service in Go that takes a timetstamp passed in as a HTTP request parameter and parses it.

A sample call is `GET /values?from=2015-02-11T15:01:00+00:00`

An example of he value that is being passed into the function is `2015-02-11T15:01:00+00:00`.

I am trying to parse it thus:

```
dateTime := request.URL.Query.Get("from")
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
formattedTime, _ := time.Parse(layout, dateTime)
```

(I am using Go's layout numbers to to do this - more information here: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants)

However, the output from this is `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`.

I should also point out that when I do a `fmt.Println(dateTime)`, I get `2015-02-11T15:01:00 00:00` (not `2015-02-11T15:01:00+00:00` as I might expect).

Also, when I hardcode a datetime into the function and parse it using time.Parse(layout, dateTime), it is parsed successfully and gives the output `2015-02-11 15:01:00 +000 GMT`.

Does anyone know what might be happening here?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1):

You should check returned errors. `time.Parse()` returns an error:

```
formattedTime, err := time.Parse(layout, dateTime)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Your error will lie in the `'+'` character in the URL query. The URL query uses [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) where the `+` sign is special: it is used to encode the space character. So when you do this:

```
dateTime := request.URL.Query.Get("from")
```

Your `dateTime` will contain the decoded value where `+` will be replaced by a space. Check it like:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", dateTime)
```

Output:

```
"2015-02-11T15:01:00 00:00"
```

And of course this is not a valid format for the layout you specified, which will give you the following error:

> parsing time "2015-02-11T15:01:00 00:00" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "" as "Z07:00"

You have to use `%2B` in the URL query which is the code for the `+` sign, and you also have to include the `Z` char which you used in your layout:

```
GET /values?from=2015-02-11T15:01:00Z%2B00:00
```

And also note that the layout has to contain the `-07:00` reference time zone and not `07:00`:

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z-07:00"
```

Then the output (`formattedTime`):

```
2015-02-11 15:01:00 +0000 UTC
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/8Ska4MDtNO):

#### If you must use `+` in the query...

If you must use the `+` query (as you claim in the comment), then working with the unescaped value would be tricky, as if time zone in query is `+`, it is replaced with space, but if the time zone is `-`, it is not!

One way is to work with the Raw query and not the decoded one. This is available in `URL.RawQuery`.

Here's a solution which assumes there is only 1 request parameter: `"from="`. It fails if there are other, please take that into account:

```
param := "from="
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00"
length := len(param) + len(layout)

if s := request.URL.RawQuery; len(s) < length || !strings.HasPrefix(s, param) {
     // unexpected query
}
dateTime := request.URL.RawQuery[len(param):length]
formattedTime, err := time.Parse(layout, dateTime)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guys!

Ah, I see - unfortunately I need to use the format `GET /values?from=2015-02-11T15:01:00+00:00` in my http request though! 

Would it be advisable to read in the **unencoded** value from the query string and try and parse it?

Comment: @Seán See my edited answer. One way is to deal with `+` and `-` time zones as they decode differently. Another way is to extract parameter value yourself using `URL.RawQuery`.

Comment: Thanks @icza - I went for the latter option, which gave me something like:

`var Url *url.URL`
`URL, _ := url.Parse(request.URL.string())`
`fromString := Url.RawQuery[5:30]`
`layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"`
`fromTime := time.Parse(layout, fromString)`

Ugly I know but I can't (for the minute) conceive of a way of making it more elegant (knowing that I have to handle the '+' sign in the query).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Seán There is absolutely no need to create a new `URL`, you can just use `request.URL`. See edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a minus before the time zone offset, so the layout should be: "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00"

https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants:

```
Numeric time zone offsets format as follows:

-0700  ±hhmm
-07:00 ±hh:mm
-07    ±hh
```

example: http://play.golang.org/p/ZG979Meuxz

When you print it out, it uses the default format, not the one you used to parse it, because it calls the String method: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String

To format it using a custom format, use Format: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format